# DRY Django querysets

Tags: python, django

I have a query which users order_by on a number of aggregated fields in a database, like so:

```
list = MyList.objects.filter(key_item=None).extra(
        select={"diff":"abs(field1+field2+field3+field4+field5+field6+field7+field8+field9+field10)"}).order_by('-diff')
```

I'm using this is several places within my code and I'd rather have it in some centralized place.

I was wondering the best way in django to reuse this.

Comment: A [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) is inherently an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable), what do you mean "access this as an iterable list." ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a manager to your model class to include that as a base filter.
For example:

```
class MyListManager(models.Manager):
    def select_diff(self):
        return self.get_queryset().extra(...)


class MyList(models.Model):
    objects = MyListManager()
```

With this you can simply do:

```
MyList.objects.select_diff().filter(...)
```

You can find more about managers [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/managers/)

One big advantage of doing this over having the queryset written down somewhere is that you can still chain the queryset with additional filters / parameters and you comply with the django standard

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I've tried a quick implementation and I'm getting an error `'function' object has no attribute 'filter'`.  Do I need to add something for the filter attribute to work?

Comment: It would appear you are doing `select_diff.filter()` instead of `select_diff().filter()` ? That error points to you not having called one of the functions so you are trying to access the filter attribute of it (which does not exist)